# Git Error: returned status code 128: stderr: fatal: not in a git directory

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, upgrade

Since we upgraded Jenkins to version 2.401.2 and git plugins to the latest version I am getting these errors with git:

[image]

[image]

#### Git Plugins versions that we have:

Git client plugin - Version 4.4.0

Git plugin - Version 5.2.0

Git server Plugin - Version 99.va_0826a_b_cdfa_d

GitHub API Plugin - Version 1.314-431.v78d72a_3fe4c3

GitHub Branch Source Plugin - Version 1732.v3f1889a_c475b_

GitHub plugin - Version 1.37.3

Any idea why we have this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I suggest taking a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And please don't [post pictures of your code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11968910), instead copy and paste the code into a code block using backticks (`) so others can more easily reproduce your error!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. It´s necessary to run the command
git config --global --add safe.directory "*"